# Rewrite into a SortedList

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
}
```

I want to collect by `Symbol`(one symbol corresponds a list of dates) and rewrite `List<MyClass> A` as `SortedList<string, List<MyClass>> B.`

```
SortedList<string, List<MyClass>> B = new SortedList<string, List<MyClass>>();
           A.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).GroupBy(o => o.Symbol)
            .Select(o => {
                B.Add(o.Key, o.ToList());
                return 1;
            });
```

Here I can not use `Foreach,` so I use `Select` instead. But the result `B` is always empty.

I am not sure whether I should open a new question, I never expect your answer is so fast......but they are almost similar, after obtain the `SortedList` B I need take some filtration as follow, but if I add the `ToList)()` I can no longer call for the `o.Key` or how to keep the `SortedList` structure after the `linq`?

```
B.Select(o => o.Value.Where(p => p.Date <= today).Take(volDay))
                .Where(o => o.Count() == volDay).ToList()
                ForEach(o => C.Add(o.Key, o.ToList());
```

Comment: Linq uses "Deferred Execution", hence your `Select()` wouldn't run until the `IEnumerable` is materialized (aka `foreach`, `ToList()`, `ToArray()` etc). But, you really shouldn't rely on `Select` to add items to another data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not enumerating the Select.

These methods do not iterate the list unless they are specifcly asked to, for example by calling ToList()

However of course you can use foreach:

```
foreach( var item in A.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Date).GroupBy(o=>o.Symbol) )
{
   B.Add( item.Key, item.ToList() );
}
```

Comment: thanks, and so this is the quickest way to rewrite the `SortedList`? And should I use `SortedList` or `Dictionary` to accelerate the visit later?

Comment: It depends on how you want to access the collection later. Dictionary has constant lookup time but is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<MyClass> A = new List<MyClass>();
        A.Add(new MyClass() { Close = 0.2m, Symbol = "Test1", Date = DateTime.Now });
        A.Add(new MyClass() { Close = 0.3m, Symbol = "Test1", Date = DateTime.Now });
        A.Add(new MyClass() { Close = 0.1m, Symbol = "Test2", Date = DateTime.Now });
        A.Add(new MyClass() { Close = 0.2m, Symbol = "Test2", Date = DateTime.Now });
        SortedList<string, List<MyClass>> B = new SortedList<string, List<MyClass>>();
        A.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).GroupBy(o => o.Symbol).ToList()
            .ForEach(o => B.Add(o.Key, o.ToList()));
        Console.WriteLine(B.Count);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Tested the code. You should be using foreach loop instead if you want to perform some operation on all records